# I keep getting 403 response error. I'm using django restframework with customized authentication method

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Inspecting the header from postman i notice, the allowed method does not include the POST. I'm unable to make request for unauthenticated routes, i get `403`.

```
class LoginUserAccountView(generics.CreateAPIView):
  serializer_class = LoginSerializer
  permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    try:
      user = User.objects.get(email=request.data['email'])
      if user.check_password(request.data['password']):
        serialized_user = UserSerializer(user).data
        access_token = generate_access_token(user)

        return Response(data={'access_token': access_token,
            'user': serialized_user}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
      else:
        return Response({'errors': 'Invalid credentials'})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      return Response({'errors': 'No user with such email!'})
```

Here is what my REST_FRAMEWORK looks like the settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    # 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    #     'accounts.authentication.CustomJWTAuthentication',
    # ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

[image: Here is a screenshot showing the postman header response.]

Answer (score 0):

You should name your method `create` instead of `post`.
Method names reflect actions, not HTTP methods.

- `list` - GET, multiple objects
- `retrieve` - GET, single object using ID
- `create` - POST
- `update` - PUT
- `partial_update` - PATCH
- `destroy` - DELETE

Take a look at ViewSet [example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example).

Comment: I'm using `post` method because i'm extending the `views.APIView`.

Comment: Can you update your question and provide the entire class?

Comment: I have update the code with the full class code.